# IMPORTHTML no Google Sheets com erro

Tags: microsoft-excel, google, google-sheets

Estou tentando criar um arquivo para pegar os dados da área/tabela de Audience Geography do Alexa (https://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/twitter.com) mas o google sheets sempre que eu tento puxar aparece um erro.

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/twitter.com";"//*[@table='demographics_div_country_table']")
```

O erro diz "O valor de Função IMPORTHTML parâmetro 2 é [`@table='demographics_div_country_table'`], mas deveria ser um dos seguintes: 'table', 'list'."

Como pegar os dados dessa tabela (com os paises, a percentagem e o rank)?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui usando a seguinte requisição:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/twitter.com";"table";2)
```

Answer (score -2):

Para usar o XPath como você mencionou, você precisa usar o IMPORTXML ao invés do IMPORTHTML.

Exemplo:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_landing"; "//a/@href")
```

Referência: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342